# Openpyxl does not append to rows, if they have already been written into

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Let's say I append 10 rows in an Excel, then I open it and delete two last rows (10th and 9th row).

Then when I try to append to this Excel again, `openpyxl` won't write to 9th and 10th row, it will start from 11th, because it had previously written something in 9th and 10th row, even though they are empty now (as you can see in the picture).[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

I use simple list of values called `columns` and then `sheet_obj.append(columns)`.

Comment: When you delete, you just delete the content - not the rows. Use the explicit delete button (in the top under Home -> Cells) instead of the `delete` keyboard button

Comment: Yeah, right after I have posted this question I tried this, and it works. Thank you sir